# A Checker function in a R package that finds the version of JDK installed in the client machine

Tags: java, r, scala, r-package

I am new to developing a package in R and I was wondering if someone can lead me in the right direction?

**My problem**

I am writing a package in R that calls Scala code. So to develop this package I assume that JDK (Java Development Kit) 1.8 is installed on any machine that uses my package.

I want to know how I can write a function that checks if Java is being installed in the machine. If so, what is its version? If Java is not installed then it prompts a message and notifies the user about the problem.

Comment: `system("java -version")` should do, right? You either get an answer with the java version, or you learn that it's either not installed or not on the system path.

Comment: Hmm, though even with `capture.output` I'm having trouble getting the result programmatically.

Comment: When I run system("java -version") in R console. I get `[1] 127` as the output.

Comment: There’s an rJava package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine:

```
> x = system2("java", args = "-version", stdout = TRUE)
> x
[1] "java version \"1.8.0_261\""                                      
[2] "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)"           
[3] "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is definitely giving me some direection. Although when I run the command I get this error.`Error in system2("java", args = "-version", stdout = TRUE) : 
  '"java"' not found`. I am working on windows 10. I am assume  system function is not really independent of operating system.

Comment: I have Java installed on my machine so I do not know why the command is not giving the right answer.

Comment: Is Java on your system path? If you open a terminal window and enter `java -version` do you get a result?

Comment: Yeah it is. For some reason I had two java paths in my environment.  I had some problem installing instant oracle in my system  before and I modified java path to trick oracle installer and now it is causing me some problem.